# scala string Tail recursion with pattern match

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am trying to write a tail recursion function to reverse string, here is the code, some reason I am not sure if the pattern match condition is preventing it from getting the reversed string as output

```
def revstring(str:String):String={
  @tailrec
  def rev(str:String,r:String):String={ 
    str match{
      case s if s.head==null =>null
      case x if x.tail.isEmpty => ""
      case _=> rev(str.tail, str.head +r) 
    }
  }
  rev(str,"")}println(revstring("Mississipi"))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.head` is never null. It'll throw an exception if the string is empty (or if it is null, which it *should never be* - nulls should never really appear in scala code). 
Also, you are returning too early - `x.tail.isEmpty` means you still have one char remaining to process. 
Finally, you always return `""` instead of the actual result.

Something like this should work:

```
  str match {
     case "" => r
     case s => rev(s.tail, s.head + r)
  }
```

As mentioned in the comment, manipulating strings like this isn't very performant. So, in real life you'd probably want to convert it into a list, reverse the list, and then `.mkstring` to put it back together.

Comment: IMHO, It is worth to clarify that this will have extremely low performance due constant conversion from string to **Array**, and that `tail` on an **Array** implies a copy as well as perpend on a **String**. It would be better to either use **Lists** of **Characters** or a `foreach` with a **StringBuilder**.

Comment: Yeah, this would suck for a string that's like a million characters long or something :)

Answer (score 0):

I Have created function which reverse the string using scala's tail recursion

```
def reverseString(str:String) = {
@tailrec
def reverseStringHelper(strTail:List[Char],reversedString :List[Char]):List[Char] = {
  strTail match {
    case Nil => reversedString
    case head :: tail => {
      reverseStringHelper(tail,head :: reversedString)
    }
  }
}
reverseStringHelper(str.toList,List[Char]()).mkString
}
```

If you found the answer helpful, please accept it.

Github Gist: https://gist.github.com/Deepak-nebhwani/0f0981027b61ff9f50904662614e7b7f